# How to fix blinking of scroll depended header while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to implement ListView with header which hiding when user scroll ListView down, and showing again when user scroll it up. But I get a problem: header is blinking when I scroll down ListView slowly. I know it happens because ListView changes size. But how to fix it?

[image]

Here is code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private static final int LIST_DATA_COUNT = 100;
    private View mHeader;
    private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHeader = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        String[] listData = new String[LIST_DATA_COUNT];
        for (int i=0;i<LIST_DATA_COUNT;i++) {
            listData[i]= String.valueOf(i);
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listData));
        listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (firstVisibleItem<mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
            Log.d("tag", "up");
            mHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (firstVisibleItem>mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
            Log.d("tag", "down");
            mHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
D/tag? up
D/tag? down
D/tag? up
D/tag? down
D/tag? up
D/tag? down
D/tag? up
D/tag? down
D/tag? up
D/tag? down
D/tag? up
D/tag? down
D/tag? up
D/tag? down
D/tag? up
D/tag? down
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `TouchListener` for the `ListView`. This may works for you.

```
 listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    startY = event.getY();//declare as global variable
                    return true;
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    float y = event.getY();
                    if(startY-y<-60){
                        Log.w(TAG, "scroll down");
                        mHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(startY-y>60){
                        Log.w(TAG, "scroll up");
                        mHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: But this is not same. My header must showing in middle of the list too. You can run my code to understand how it works.

Comment: @BArtWell Once try my updated answer and let me know is it working for you or not?

Comment: yes, it working well. But `return true;` is not needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can show header as overlay. This will prevent ListView resizing. For the first version just try to change ListView and TextView order.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, that is not as desired. Header must have fixed position and must hiding when user scroll down ListView. So ListView will always resize and this behaviour is normal.